# C - Non-obtrusive graphics library?

Tags: c, graphics

I've used GUI's in other languages but never a low language like C. I've looked online and found that **SDL** is the ideal choice but unfortunately I don't like the fact that it runs within a window of it's own. Is there any way to just draw directly to the screen without any other features?

For example, if I wanted to draw a shape that stays ontop of other windows, but is **not** just a stage that has its property set to *transparent*.

If that's not possible, then I'm looking for something as simple and as hassle free as possible. My goal is to create [something like this](https://youtu.be/HQYsFshbkYw?t=235)

Comment: "Is there any way to just draw directly to the screen without any other features?" No, not inside a modern day OS, which has its own GUI. If you want more specific answers for *your* OS, you'd better mention it somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there any way to just draw directly to the screen without any other features?

This depends on what environment you run in, but in general: No, if you're running on a system with some kind of display management (you are, unless you forgot to mention you're doing bare-bone graphics on some microcontroller.) someone has to assign you a kind of window to do drawing.

> For example, if I wanted to draw a shape that stays ontop of other windows, but is not just a stage that has its property set to transparent.

As said, you'll need someone to give you a buffer to draw on. And that's exactly what a window is.

> If that's not possible, then I'm looking for something as simple and as hassle free as possible. My goal is to create something like this

SDL & OpenGL, or really: Use some game/3D engine.

Comment: Amazing response by the way. 

Subquestion, how do you think programs like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yu8YNHvyVSY), [this](https://youtu.be/td6gCz4dfnw?t=58), or [this](https://youtu.be/mZu8e0OyaAI?t=97) might work in terms of graphical stuff? Note, I am not making a virus.

Comment: the two windows malware programs simply use transparent windows (the first one modifies the "desktop background window"). The dos thing abuses the hardware's text output routines by overwriting memory. Not portable at all to graphics hardware.

Comment: Would you mind living in my mind so I can possess your god-like programming knowledge?